# How to make jslint less verbose

Tags: javascript, warnings, jslint, lint

My "IDE" of choice (it's not a real IDE) is Sublime Text 2.

There are nice plugins for this editor. One that I enjoy using a lot is [SublimeClang](https://github.com/quarnster/SublimeClang/): It parses your C/C++ code as you write it and shows you where errors and warnings are, just like a "real" IDE. This is fantastic because it cuts out the code/compilation cycle so I only ever need to go back to my terminal once I have my code already written because I can see my errors as I am working on the code.

I had hoped that jsLint (there are [plugins](https://github.com/fbzhong/sublime-jslint) for integrating this with the editor as well) would help accomplish the same task for me so that I can spot syntax errors before I test my page in the browser. Oftentimes the best way to do this involves uploading the entire file to the server and loading it up in the browser: While this workflow can be heavily streamlined already there is a lot of appeal to being able to locally check the code before uploading.

The problem I have with jslint is that it throws out way too many opinions about esoteric stylistic  choices, many of which I do not care for. You want me to put all my declarations together in one line? No thank you, I have all of these comments here next to the variables, I'm keeping those comments!

Are there flags I can provide to jslint so that it will only warn me about syntax errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people feel the same way you do about JSLint. One result is the alternative JSHint. Many people find its defaults more to their liking. There are Sublime plugins for it too. Two of them are listed at http://www.jshint.com/platforms/.

Comment: Yes jsLint is apparently not what I am looking for. The Sublime V8 plugin (or something else that essentially uses V8 to check the JS) is more like it.

Comment: SublimeLinter with node.js jshint is just what the doctor ordered. Its performance with real-time scanning is impressive as well.

Answer (score 0):

JSLint does have [several options](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#options) to change its behavior.

It looks like you can define these in the `sublime-jslint.sublime-settings` file included with the plugin you linked to (in the "jslint_options" section).